# Passing xp:link parameters through custom control

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have a custom control with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:panel tagName="li">
        <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[${javascript:@If(view.getPageName().equals(compositeData.linkPage), "active", "")}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
        <xp:link escape="true"
            text="${javascript:compositeData.LinkLabel}"
            value="${javascript:compositeData.linkPage}"
            parameters="${javascript:compositeData.parameters}">
        </xp:link>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

This is the property definition tree of the control:

[image: Property definition of custom control]

I try to use the custom control like this:

```
            <xc:sideMenuPageLink LinkLabel="Registration"
                linkPage="/Registration.xsp">
                <xc:this.parameters>
                    <xc:parameters name="id" value="new"></xc:parameters>
                </xc:this.parameters>
            </xc:sideMenuPageLink>
```

When I build my application, I get the following error:

> The method addParameter(Parameter) in the type UIOutputLink is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

on SideMenuPageLink.java (my custom control)

How can I pass the parameters for the link from my Xpage to the Custom Control?

Comment: What is the type of the "parameters" parameter in the Custom Control definition?

Comment: "parameters" is a group containing 'name' and 'value', both Strings. I don't think I can assign a type to a group.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that parameters have to passed one by one, not as a single object.
You may want to try the following code, which works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:panel tagName="li">
        <xp:this.styleClass><! [CDATA[${javascript:@If(view.getPageName().equals(compositeData.linkPage), "active", "")}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
        <xp:link escape="true"
            text="${compositeData.LinkLabel}"
            value="${compositeData.linkPage}">
            <xp:this.parameters>
                <xp:parameter
                    name="${compositeData.parameters.name}"
                    value="${compositeData.parameters.value}">
                </xp:parameter>
            </xp:this.parameters>
        </xp:link>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Edit 2019-01-30: Corrected typos

Comment: Sorry about the late response. Since I do not know the number of parameters upfront, I need to be able to pass an array of parameters to the link. Your answer only works for one parameter.